# How to create multiple triangles based on given number of simulations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Below is my code:

```
triangle = cl.load_sample('genins')

# Use bootstrap sampler to get resampled triangles
bootstrapdataframe = cl.BootstrapODPSample(n_sims=4, random_state=42).fit(triangle).resampled_triangles_

#converting to dataframe
resampledtriangledf = bootstrapdataframe.to_frame()
print(resampledtriangledf)
```

In above code i mentioned n_sims(number of simulation)=4. So it generates below datafame:

```
0   2001    12   254,926 
0   2001    24   535,877 
0   2001    36   1,355,613 
0   2001    48   2,034,557 
0   2001    60   2,311,789 
0   2001    72   2,539,807 
0   2001    84   2,724,773 
0   2001    96   3,187,095 
0   2001    108  3,498,646 
0   2001    120  3,586,037 
0   2002    12   542,369 
0   2002    24   1,016,927 
0   2002    36   2,201,329 
0   2002    48   2,923,381 
0   2002    60   3,711,305 
0   2002    72   3,914,829 
0   2002    84   4,385,757 
0   2002    96   4,596,072 
0   2002    108  5,047,861 
0   2003    12   235,361 
0   2003    24   960,355 
0   2003    36   1,661,972 
0   2003    48   2,643,370 
0   2003    60   3,372,684 
0   2003    72   3,642,605 
0   2003    84   4,160,583 
0   2003    96   4,480,332 
0   2004    12   764,553 
0   2004    24   1,703,557 
0   2004    36   2,498,418 
0   2004    48   3,198,358 
0   2004    60   3,524,562 
0   2004    72   3,884,971 
0   2004    84   4,268,241 
0   2005    12   381,670 
0   2005    24   1,124,054 
0   2005    36   2,026,434 
0   2005    48   2,863,902 
0   2005    60   3,039,322 
0   2005    72   3,288,253 
0   2006    12   320,332 
0   2006    24   1,022,323 
0   2006    36   1,830,842 
0   2006    48   2,676,710 
0   2006    60   3,375,172 
0   2007    12   330,361 
0   2007    24   1,463,348 
0   2007    36   2,771,839 
0   2007    48   4,003,745 
0   2008    12   282,143 
0   2008    24   1,782,267 
0   2008    36   2,898,699 
0   2009    12   362,726 
0   2009    24   1,277,750 
0   2010    12   321,247 
1   2001    12   219,021 
1   2001    24   755,975 
1   2001    36   1,360,298 
1   2001    48   2,062,947 
1   2001    60   2,356,983 
1   2001    72   2,781,187 
1   2001    84   2,987,837 
1   2001    96   3,118,952 
1   2001    108  3,307,522 
1   2001    120  3,455,107 
1   2002    12   302,932 
1   2002    24   1,022,459 
1   2002    36   1,634,938 
1   2002    48   2,538,708 
1   2002    60   3,005,695 
1   2002    72   3,274,719 
1   2002    84   3,356,499 
1   2002    96   3,595,361 
1   2002    108  4,100,065 
1   2003    12   489,934 
1   2003    24   1,233,438 
1   2003    36   2,471,849 
1   2003    48   3,672,629 
1   2003    60   4,157,489 
1   2003    72   4,498,470 
1   2003    84   4,587,579 
1   2003    96   4,816,232 
1   2004    12   518,680 
1   2004    24   1,209,705 
1   2004    36   2,019,757 
1   2004    48   2,997,820 
1   2004    60   3,630,442 
1   2004    72   3,881,093 
1   2004    84   4,080,322 
1   2005    12   453,963 
1   2005    24   1,458,504 
1   2005    36   2,036,506 
1   2005    48   2,846,464 
1   2005    60   3,280,124 
1   2005    72   3,544,597 
1   2006    12   369,755 
1   2006    24   1,209,117 
1   2006    36   1,973,136 
1   2006    48   3,034,294 
1   2006    60   3,537,784 
1   2007    12   477,788 
1   2007    24   1,524,537 
1   2007    36   2,170,391 
1   2007    48   3,355,093 
1   2008    12   250,690 
1   2008    24   1,546,986 
1   2008    36   2,996,737 
1   2009    12   271,270 
1   2009    24   1,446,353 
1   2010    12   510,114 
2   2001    12   170,866 
2   2001    24   797,338 
2   2001    36   1,663,610 
2   2001    48   2,293,697 
2   2001    60   2,607,067 
2   2001    72   2,979,479 
2   2001    84   3,127,308 
2   2001    96   3,285,338 
2   2001    108  3,574,272 
2   2001    120  3,630,610 
2   2002    12   259,060 
2   2002    24   1,011,092 
2   2002    36   1,851,504 
2   2002    48   2,705,313 
2   2002    60   3,195,774 
2   2002    72   3,766,008 
2   2002    84   3,944,417 
2   2002    96   4,234,043 
2   2002    108  4,763,664 
2   2003    12   239,981 
2   2003    24   983,484 
2   2003    36   1,929,785 
2   2003    48   2,497,929 
2   2003    60   2,972,887 
2   2003    72   3,313,868 
2   2003    84   3,727,432 
2   2003    96   4,024,122 
2   2004    12   77,522 
2   2004    24   729,401 
2   2004    36   1,473,914 
2   2004    48   2,376,313 
2   2004    60   2,999,197 
2   2004    72   3,372,020 
2   2004    84   3,887,883 
2   2005    12   321,598 
2   2005    24   1,132,502 
2   2005    36   1,710,504 
2   2005    48   2,438,620 
2   2005    60   2,801,957 
2   2005    72   3,182,466 
2   2006    12   255,407 
2   2006    24   1,275,141 
2   2006    36   2,083,421 
2   2006    48   3,144,579 
2   2006    60   3,891,772 
2   2007    12   338,120 
2   2007    24   1,275,697 
2   2007    36   2,238,715 
2   2007    48   3,615,323 
2   2008    12   310,214 
2   2008    24   1,237,156 
2   2008    36   2,563,326 
2   2009    12   271,093 
2   2009    24   1,523,131 
2   2010    12   430,591 
3   2001    12   330,887 
3   2001    24   831,193 
3   2001    36   1,601,374 
3   2001    48   2,188,879 
3   2001    60   2,662,773 
3   2001    72   3,086,976 
3   2001    84   3,332,247 
3   2001    96   3,317,279 
3   2001    108  3,576,659 
3   2001    120  3,613,563 
3   2002    12   358,263 
3   2002    24   1,139,259 
3   2002    36   2,236,375 
3   2002    48   3,163,464 
3   2002    60   3,715,130 
3   2002    72   4,295,638 
3   2002    84   4,502,105 
3   2002    96   4,769,139 
3   2002    108  5,323,304 
3   2003    12   489,934 
3   2003    24   1,570,352 
3   2003    36   3,123,215 
3   2003    48   4,189,299 
3   2003    60   4,819,070 
3   2003    72   5,306,689 
3   2003    84   5,560,371 
3   2003    96   5,827,003 
3   2004    12   419,727 
3   2004    24   1,308,884 
3   2004    36   2,118,936 
3   2004    48   2,906,732 
3   2004    60   3,561,577 
3   2004    72   3,934,400 
3   2004    84   4,010,511 
3   2005    12   389,217 
3   2005    24   1,173,226 
3   2005    36   1,794,216 
3   2005    48   2,528,910 
3   2005    60   3,474,035 
3   2005    72   3,908,999 
3   2006    12   291,940 
3   2006    24   1,136,674 
3   2006    36   1,915,614 
3   2006    48   2,693,930 
3   2006    60   3,375,601 
3   2007    12   506,055 
3   2007    24   1,684,660 
3   2007    36   2,678,739 
3   2007    48   3,545,156 
3   2008    12   282,143 
3   2008    24   1,536,490 
3   2008    36   2,458,789 
3   2009    12   271,093 
3   2009    24   1,199,897 
3   2010    12   266,359
```

Using above dataframe I have to create 4 triangles based on Toatal column:
For example:

```
 Row Labels          12         24           36          48        60        72           84            96         108         120      Grand Total
    2001          254,926    535,877     1,355,613   2,034,557   2,311,789   2,539,807   2,724,773   3,187,095   3,498,646   3,586,037   22,029,119 
    2002          542,369    1,016,927   2,201,329   2,923,381   3,711,305   3,914,829   4,385,757   4,596,072   5,047,861               28,339,832 
    2003          235,361    960,355     1,661,972   2,643,370   3,372,684   3,642,605   4,160,583   4,480,332                           21,157,261 
    2004          764,553    1,703,557   2,498,418   3,198,358   3,524,562   3,884,971   4,268,241                                       19,842,659 
    2005          381,670    1,124,054   2,026,434   2,863,902   3,039,322   3,288,253                                                   12,723,635 
    2006          320,332    1,022,323   1,830,842   2,676,710   3,375,172                                                               9,225,377 
    2007          330,361    1,463,348   2,771,839   4,003,745                                                                           8,569,294 
    2008          282,143    1,782,267   2,898,699                                                                                       4,963,110 
    2009          362,726    1,277,750                                                                                                   1,640,475 
    2010          321,247                                                                                                                321,247 
    Grand Total   3,795,687  10,886,456  17,245,147  20,344,022  19,334,833 17,270,466  15,539,355  12,263,499  8,546,507  3,586,037  128,812,009
            .
    .
    .
```

Like this i need 4 triangles (4 is number of simulation) using 1st dataframe.
If user gives s_sims=900 then it creates 900 totals values based on this we have to create 900 triangles.
In above triangle i just displayed only 1 triangle for 0th value. But i neet triangle for 1 ,2 and 3 also.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['sample_size'] = pd.to_numeric(df['sample_size'].str.replace(',',''))
df.pivot_table('sample_size','year', 'no', aggfunc='first')\
  .pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x,x.sum().to_frame('Grand Total').T]))
```

Output:

```
no                 12          24          36          48          60          72          84          96         108        120
2001          254926.0    535877.0   1355613.0   2034557.0   2311789.0   2539807.0   2724773.0   3187095.0  3498646.0  3586037.0
2002          542369.0   1016927.0   2201329.0   2923381.0   3711305.0   3914829.0   4385757.0   4596072.0  5047861.0        NaN
2003          235361.0    960355.0   1661972.0   2643370.0   3372684.0   3642605.0   4160583.0   4480332.0        NaN        NaN
2004          764553.0   1703557.0   2498418.0   3198358.0   3524562.0   3884971.0   4268241.0         NaN        NaN        NaN
2005          381670.0   1124054.0   2026434.0   2863902.0   3039322.0   3288253.0         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
2006          320332.0   1022323.0   1830842.0   2676710.0   3375172.0         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
2007          330361.0   1463348.0   2771839.0   4003745.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
2008          282143.0   1782267.0   2898699.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
2009          362726.0   1277750.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
2010          321247.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
Grand Total  3795688.0  10886458.0  17245146.0  20344023.0  19334834.0  17270465.0  15539354.0  12263499.0  8546507.0  3586037.0
```

Comment: I think this is for only one triangle right?

Comment: In my question I just displayed triangle for 0. But i need till 3 (Because I entered simulation number is 4) @Scott Boston

Comment: Any one please help me out

Comment: I tried your code but it just creates only one triangle. @Scott Boston

Comment: @Dark_Devil Updated to change the dtype of sample_size column.